# Why is AD DS DNS working only in Host-Only mode between 2 VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, active-directory

I'm using Parallels Desktop...

1. Why when I put:

- my ADDS Windows Server VM in host-only
- my Windows 10 VM in host-only

from my Windows 10 VM I can join the domain
...while host-only does not allow communications between VMs, only between the VM and the host....

2. but

Why when I put:

- my ADDS Windows Server VM in bridge mode
- my Windows 10 VM in bridge mode

since my Windows 10 VM, I cannot join the domain???
Yet we should see that the 2 VMs are like independent PCs on my local network.... ?

I don't understand...

Comment: Which DNS server does the Windows 10 VM use when it's in bridge mode and when it's in host-only mode, respectively? Is that server able to resolve your AD domain and its subdomains?

Comment: W10 VM use the IP of the WSRV AD DS VM as DNS on ipV4 and WSRV AD DS VM uses 127.0.0.1 as dns

Comment: The thing is, their IPs most likely has changed (because the DHCP server, if any, and hence the IP subnet will probably be different when you changed to bridge mode, assuming they are bridged to the VM host physical LAN). Have you maybe forgot to update some related settings?

Comment: `while host-only does not allow communications between VMs` that's not what host-only means btw. It really just means "(by default) goes no "further" than the VM host": https://download.parallels.com/workstation/v6/en_us/parallels/update1-hf1/docs/Parallels%20Workstation%20User's%20Guide/22428.htm (More precisely, it means the "hypervisor software" will not make the host do L3 forwarding / act as default gateway / source NAT / DNS forwarding (but it does not necessarily mean you cannot set those up yourself).

Comment: @John the last comment wasn't for you but the OP (apparently you skipped the fact that it's quoting the OP instead of you, as you skip everything like usual). As for your deleted answer, yes I downvoted, because it's literally not answering anything and even contradict with the scenario and what you linked/quote. For the record, I would only bother to downvote when an answer is really misleading / bad, so in case you have a feeling like I'm targeting you or something, sorry, but no.